# White Spacing Woocommerce Single Product Page

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I need a small change on my single product page. https://www.narwal.shop/product/bonsai/

I need a small vertical white spacing between the size selection and the quantity box.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will need css, add bottom margin to the size selection. For example:

```
.size-selection { margin-bottom: 5px }
```

To do this, you need to know the class of the element. Open Dev Tools in your browser with F12 and find the element in the source code.

[Here](http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-easily-add-custom-css-to-your-wordpress-site/) you can see how to add custom css to your WordPress site.